# SVG <g> selection with localStorage.getItem()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

My web page includes two `<iframe>` that refers two html files including an SVG in each other. From `file1.html` I click an svg element, generate an `id` number, and store it via

`localStorage.setItem("element1id",ID1)`.

The SVG in `file2.html` also use same `ID1` as `<g id="ID1">....</g>` So I retrieve `ID1` , try to find the element and assign a `var`, and add some attributes with the following codes:

`var selectedID = localStorage.getItem("element1id")
$("'#"+selectedID+"'").attr(*adding some new attributes*)`

With this code console gives me `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: '#0BTBFw6f90Nfh9rP1dlXrr'`. (As you guess this long string is the `ID1`)

I re-checked the selection by manually writing the `ID1` like following:

```
$("#0BTBFw6f90Nfh9rP1dlXrr").attr(*adding some new attributes*)
```

In this case there is no problem. It finds the `<g>` element and adds the attributes.
Has anyone experienced this problem before? or am I missing sth.? Thanks.

Comment: You're adding single quote characters when constructing your dynamic query string, causing the syntax error.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I changed the quotes, but it gave the same error again: `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: "#0BTBFw6f90Nfh9rP1dlXrr"`

Comment: @JeremyBanks In DOM, IDs can start with a digit, but it's not a valid CSS identifier, so `[id="0BTBFw6f90Nfh9rP1dlXrr"]` should be used instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing

```
$("'#"+selectedID+"'").attr(*adding some new attributes*);
```

With

```
$("#"+selectedID).attr(*adding some new attributes*);
```

in your code

Comment: Aha!! such an easy mistake. Worked well. Thanks

Comment: Use `CSS.escape` to prevent CSS injection.